OJS PDF.js PDF Viewer
enter image description here
I have a problem with pdf.js (plugin in OJS for pdf viewer) when using HTTP the document can be displayed, but when switching to HTTPS the document does not display and an error message appears:
PDF.js v2.5.207 (build: 0974d6052)
Message: file origin does not match viewer's
I have changed in the config.inc.php section in the base url section to https but still can't, please help me, ojs masters, I have a headache what should I do for 2 days I'm stuck here
pdf can appear well
